# How to generate A template function for all my variables in my class?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using Eclipse for RCP and RAP Developers
`Version: Kepler Service Release 2(32 bit)`

I have a class looking like this:

```
public class Builder
{
    double  booking_id;
    Date beg_dt_tm;
    Date end_dt_tm;
    boolean status_flag;
    String status_meaning;
    double encntr_id;
    double appt_type_cd;
    String appt_type_disp;
    String appt_type_display;
    double location_cd;
    String location_display;
    double sch_role_cd;
    String role_meaning;
    double primary_resource_cd;
    String primary_resource_display;
    long order_qual_cnt;
    List<Order_QualSDO>order_qual = new ArrayList<Order_QualSDO>();
    double sch_event_id;
    double schedule_id;
    long schedule_seq;
}
```

For which I want to generate a function like this:

```
public Builder booking_id(double booking_id)
{
    this.booking_id = booking_id;
    return this;
}
```

For all the variables in the `Builder Class` . Now I know how to generate getters and setters, but I don't know if we can generate custom made function definitions in Eclipse like these. 
If yes How?
If No. Well I better get started, because the next class has 110 variables. :(
Help is Appreciated.

Comment: Before anyone down votes kindly explain your down vote and give me some time to correct it. I think that would generate a more healthy environment rather than just down voting and leaving the person clueless.

Comment: Why do you want to return the Builder object? You need to have a reference of it to actually call the method `booking_id()` anyway. So why can't you just use a default setter in eclipse? If you just want to add some other functionality to the setter without returning anything you can do so from `Project -> Properties -> Java Code Style -> Code Templates -> Code -> Setter Body`

Comment: That is how it is required in the project i am working in. Giving details as to why i am using would go a little out of context. Well using a default setter doesn't give me that much control over the setting the return type of the method+ have customized method definition. I would like to have complete control rather than editing the generated code.

Comment: The design here is evidently for a "fluent" sort of API... you return the Builder so you can chain calls. `builder.booking_id(54).status_flag(true).appt_type_cd(134).schedule_id(78)` etc etc.

Comment: @dcsohl That is correct, but line between fluent interface API and builder pattern is blurry. Hence the word Builder rather than fluent.